# Gravitational Wave Interference

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, gravitational-waves

Can gravitational waves interfere like water waves and light waves? If not, can someone explain what about these waves make them uninterferable?

Comment: Yes they will interfere as long as you don't veer too far outside the zone of applicability of linearized gravity.

Comment: They can interfere but not via linear superposition since the equations of GR are non linear.

Comment: @irishphysics halp